# Can't login to OpenShift Origin with administrator (system:admin)

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I installed OpenShift origin (openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit) and when I tried to login with `oc login` it asks for username and password.
If I type any username like `bob` and then any password like `123` it login successfully but without permissions.

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-12 centos]# oc get pods
No resources found.
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "bob" cannot list pods in the namespace "default": no RBAC policy matched
```

So I tried to login as the admin `system:admin` but it asks for password and I don't have the password, I have two certificates of two `system:admin` users in the `/root/.kube/config` file:

```
-name: system:admin/10-0-0-12:8443  
 ...
-name: system:admin/127-0-0-1:8443
```

How can I login as the admin of the cluster ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it.

tl;dr I copied the original config file to the `/root/.kube/config`, add it to the environment variables and upload the cluster:

```
cp /home/centos/openshift.local.clusterup/openshift-apiserver/admin.kubeconfig /root/.kube/config
export KUBECONFIG=/root/.kube/config
oc cluster up
```

Everything works fine now.

**Details**

> system:admin credentials live in a client certificate. If you get
>   prompted for a password, that means your $KUBECONFIG file does not
>   contain those credentials.   Try to login with "system:admin" user
>   using both, the default kube config and the config from
>   /etc/origin/master.
>
> /# oc login -u system:admin  --config=/etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig
>   /# oc login -u system:admin  --config=/root/.kube/config   If login using  /etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig is done successfully just
>   simply copy this file to /home/user/.kube/config (kube-config file
>   inside the linux users home directory)
>
> The system admin ~/.kube/config file that is originally generated
>   after installing OpenShift 3.x+ is directly copied from the
>   admin.kubeconfig.
>
> To restore the ~/.kube/config file so that a administrator can log in
>   as system:admin just copy the admin.kubeconfig file.
>
> cp /etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig  ~/.kube/config.
>
> After that try login again without providing any config file in oc
>   login command.